# Why would I ever want `setRetainInstance(false)`? - Or - The correct way to handle device rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, fragment, lifecycle

*Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of this. This is a kind of clarifying question since I haven't seen it explicitly written anywhere.*

In Android 4, you can call `setRetainInstance(true)` on a `Fragment` so that on configuration changes (which basically means device rotation), the `Fragment` java object isn't destroyed and a new instance of it isn't created. That is, the instance is retained.

This is much more sane and less infuriating than in Android 1-3 since you don't have to deal with `onRetainNonConfiguration`<strike>`State`</strike>`Instance()` and bundle up all your data so it can be passed to the new `Fragment` (or `Activity`) instance only to be unbundled again. It's basically what you would expect to happen, and arguably how it should have worked for `Activity`s from the beginning.

With `setRetainInstance(true)` the view is also recreated (`onCreateView()` is called) on rotation as you would expect. And I assume (not tested) that resource resolution (`layout` vs `layout-land`) works.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Why wasn't it like this with `Activities` from the beginning.
2. Why isn't this the default? Is there ever any reason why you *would* actually want your `Fragment` to be pointlessly destroyed and recreated on rotation? Because I can't think of any.

## Edit

To clarify how I would do it:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    // All the data.
    String mDataToDisplay;
    // etc.

    // All the views.
    TextView mViewToDisplayItIn;
    // etc.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mDataToDisplay = readFromSomeFileOrWhatever(); // Ignoring threading issues for now.
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // At this point if mViewToDisplayItIn was not null, the old one will be GC'd.
        mViewToDisplayItIn = view.findViewById(R.id.the_text_view);
        mViewToDisplayItIn.setText(mDataToDisplay);
    }

    // Optionally:
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        // All the view (and activity) to be GC'd.
        mViewToDisplayItIn = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> so that on configuration changes (which basically means device rotation)

And changing locale, changing SIMs, changing default font size, plugging in or removing an external keyboard, putting the device in a dock or removing it from same, etc.

> you don't have to deal with onRetainNonConfigurationState()

That's `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

> bundle up all your data so it can be passed to the new Fragment (or Activity) instance only to be unbundled again

Your data should already be "bundled" (e.g., instance of private static inner class) and therefore it would not need to be "bundled" or "unbundled". Also, it frequently should not be "all your data", unless you are a fan of memory leaks.

> And I assume (not tested) that resource resolution (layout vs layout-land) works.

Correct.

> Is there ever any reason why you would actually want your Fragment to be pointlessly destroyed and recreated on rotation?

Sure.

As you note, all widgets are recreated, so data members tied to widgets are not only unnecessary to retain. Unless you specifically reset those to `null` on a retained fragment somehow, until `onCreateView()` is called again, those data members would hold onto the old widgets, which would hold onto the old activity instance, which would prevent that old activity instance from being garbage collected. AFAIK, `onCreateView()` is not going to be called until the fragment is going to be redisplayed, which may not be for quite some time (the fragment is not used in the new orientation, or the fragment is for some page in a `ViewPager` that the user visited in the old orientation but does not revisit in the new orientation, etc.). That means that the retained fragment may keep the old activity object around for a substantial period of time. Depending on what *else* that activity may have held onto (e.g., large `Bitmap` objects), that could be bad.

Similarly, a fragment that itself holds onto large data, where that fragment may or may not be used after the configuration change, is one that should not be retained.

Also, there will be fragments that simply have nothing needing to be retained (e.g., all data is populated by `Loaders`, which are already aware of configuration changes and handle them appropriately).

And so on.

A default of fragments being not retained is the safest course of action, with respect to garbage collection issues. You can opt into having some fragments be retained, but then the onus is on *you* to make sure that you are not screwing yourself by doing that.

Comment: Many points! 1. I've never seen any fragments bundle data in a private static inner class, and I work on Google's code quite a lot. Can you provide a link where they recommend that? 2. Surely view member variables (i.e. `mProgressView` and so on) will be overwritten when `onCreateView()` is called again? Or you can `=null` them in `onDestroyView()`. 3. "Normal" `Activity`s and `Fragment`s can be retained for a long time after they are hidden, so I don't see how that is any different. Cheers for reply!

Comment: @Timmmm: 1. They don't -- I do. :-) 2. You need to remember to `null` them in `onDestroyView()`. 3. But in this case the activity is destroyed, not hidden, yet cannot be GC'd because of the references from the retained fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the first question. It *should* have been like that from the beginning. I guess someone at Google thought they're *really* smart coming up with this scheme.

The second question, however, is much easier. This isn't the default because this isn't what Android develops have learned to expect. Android develops know the instance dies on rotation and expect it. Changing the default would have made a lot of developers really pissed off.

Comment: Fixing something would have pissed developers off because they were used to it being broken. Seriously?

Comment: Changing the behavior of an existing component would assuredly piss off the devs.
Not the passionate devs that hear about this change but the 'random' ones that suddenly discover that their code no longer works with new versions of the SDK would be pissed off.

Comment: I think you guys are talking about different things: Making `Activity` work like this by default is obviously impossible - that train sailed long ago. But they only added fragments and `setRetainInstance()` very recently; they could have made it the default for fragments. My guess is the opted for consistency over having half the API sane, and half crazy.

Comment: Fragments were added with Android 3.0, quite a few years before 4.0 came out.

Comment: Android 3.0 is only 18 months old! Maybe you meant "quite a few months"? :-)

Comment: I would assume retaining instance state of fragments can easily lead to circular references which prevent proper gc. I wouldn't want my fragments to retain state unless I explicitly tell them to do so. On the same token I wouldn't want to use 'view-less' retaining fragments just as data holders, e.g. for adapters or async tasks as suggested in some places. A simple Application subclass as holder has much less overhead than a Fragment.